# Most Likely Location using Multiple Gaussians

Tags: statistics, probability

I came across to the following question for locating a person's location given some possible locations as Gaussians.

> The person is likely to be close to a road. The probability at any
>   point is given by a Gaussian function of its shortest distance to the
>   road. The function peaks at zero and has 95% of its total integral
>   within +/-2730m.
>
> A probability distribution centered around a tower also informs us of
>   the person's location. The distribution's radial profile is log-normal
>   with a mean of 4700m and a mode of 3877m in every direction.
>
> A satellite offers further information: with 95% probability person is
>   located within 2400m distance of the satellite's path (assuming a
>   normal probability distribution)
>
> Tower GPS coordinates
>
> 52.516288,13.377689
>
> Satellite path is a great circle path between coordinates
>
> 52.590117,13.39915
>
> 52.437385,13.553989
>
> Road can be approximated as piecewise linear between the following
>   coordinates:
>
> 52.529198,13.274099
>
> 52.531835,13.29234 ...

I could not figure out if I should use 2D Gaussians centered on a point, or multiple 1D Gaussians? Road is easy (I think) 1D Gaussians based on given coordinates that extend to multiple directions. Not sure what to do with the tower, and circular path. More basic question is, say I have 3 2D Gaussias centered on (10,10), (20,20), (40,40) with covariance diag([30,30]), where is the reqion with the highest probability overlap?

I guess numerically the world can be divided into a grid, for each grid we can calculate the influence of each Gaussian, add then up. The grid with the highest value would be the most likely position. I am just curious if there is an easier way of solving this analytically.